# Keras model.predict function not giving similar results as model.evaluate

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have trained an image classification model using Keras. The model after training has 95% accuracy on training data and using model.evaluate on an untouched validation data, I get ~92.8% accuracy.

But when I use model.predict function instead to get the prediction probabilities and get the predicted class with maximum probability, I get ~80% accuracy.

The complete code is available as a colab notebook on the following link - https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RQ2KnT2sVsdCAWfpsDj_kcMZiqiwJrpc?usp=sharing

You should be able to run everything and see the difference in accuracy. The problem lies in the code blocks as shown below

[image: Accuracy Issue shown in Google Colab Notebook hosted on the above link]

Answer (score 0):

To make both the accuracies from `predict_generator` and `evaluate_generator` same, you have to set the following 3 things in your functions as parameters:

```
shuffle = False
pickle_safe = True
workers = 1
```

Your program might be running on different threads and these settings make it run on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for the help Sahith. But this reduces the accuracy in evaluate_generator as well as predict_generator. There still is a big accuracy difference in the 2 methods. The collab notebook contains the solution at the end if you would like to refer.

Comment: Setting worker = 0 gives the bigger delta in the result but worker = 1 reduces that difference. Now the only question remains, is the model accuracy this low ? Using "shuffle = True" on the validation data (although weird) increases the accuracy to 91%.Validation data was never used for training the model in anyway. So shuffling or not shuffling the data in the generator should not change the accuracy in any way. Should it ?

Comment: My bad, I have corrected it in the answer. Thanks for pointing that out. I believe the accuracy increased significantly because you're probably running less epochs. If you increase the number of epochs, with or without shuffle should give similar accuracy.

Comment: Since the data is quite big (700K) images the model converges with respect to loss after 4-5 epochs which happened in my case. Does running it for more epochs with flattened loss would make it better ?

Comment: Not really. As the loss curve starts flattening out, the model is not expected to do better. It would mostly give same results.

Comment: Thats what I expected. I have posted this on the official keras github as an issue. Waiting for them to get back on this issue https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/14118. Thanks for you help. If you find anything about why the shuffle is leading to this issue please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I could find so far after having posted the issue here and keras official github (without any answer for weeks) is that instead of using Keras, I used tf.keras. Most of the implementation stayed the same. And the "Shuffle" option is definitely messing up the accuracy. The lower accuracy with "Shuffle = False" is a bug in the keras implementation probably. The tf.keras implementation gives the same result in the "evaluate_generator" function. And the predict and evaluate function outputs with respect to accuracy match. I hope if other people encounter this error, they don't waste as much time as I did on the issue.